# Elements that grow away from each other

Tags: html, css

I have site that I want to look like this:

[image]

but instead it looks like this:

[image]

this is my html:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="left"> 
    <div class="leftPoints">
      <b>Supporting Points, text area, etc</b>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="rightPoints">
      <b>Contesting Points, text area, etc</b>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
       blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my css:

```
#wrap
{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.left
{
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
}

.leftPoints
{
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.right
{
    float: right;
    width: 500 px;
}

.rightPoints
{
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

#footer
{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I feel like this should be easy, but I'm not sure what keywords to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change class .right to float left.  That will give you the desired look.  To have it center in the page, play with the .main wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I don't really understand how float works yet.

Answer (score 0):

They are floating left and right, so that is how they should look.

You could make their parent element much narrower.